# Можно ли запустить метод start не используя launch?

Tags: java, javafx

Для запуска метода `start()` в javafx нужно в `main()` написать `Application.launch(args)`. 
Это надо делать в классе, в котором переопределен метод `start()`. А если я хочу запустить javafx из другого класса? В классе, в котором переопределен `start`, я написал метод `reLaunch(String[] args)`, в котором написал `Application.launch(args)`. Потом, из другого класса из метода `main()` вызвал reLaunch. Но все равно не получается.

P.S. Я так понял, что запустить `launch()` в классе, в котором нет `main()`, не получится, из-за `args`. Есть способ запускать без `args`?

```
class Clock extend Application {
   ... reLaunch(String[] args) { Application.launch(args) }
}

class Start {
   ... main(...) {
   Clock clock = new Clock(); clock.reLaunch(args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо передать в метод launch класс, унаследованный от Application. Т.к. FX стартует из того-же класса, то это будет launch(Clock.class). Не уверен, что для этого надо вообще создавать экземпляр Cloak. Application.launch(Clock.class) может сработать.